# Saint John NB to US Border at St Stephen Calais, Maine by taxi

Tags: usa, canada, borders, taxis

I want to go to the Canada-US Border in New Brunswick St Stephen / Calais, Maine.

Is there is any taxi to take me there from Saint John bus terminal?

Comment: You're aware it's 107km/66 miles and may cost quite a lot by taxi?

Answer (score 2):

Seems [Diamond Taxis](http://www.diamondtaxisaintjohn.com/rates.html) would charge $120.